# Listener failed to start, TNS-01150 and TNS-01153

Tags: oracle, listener, oracle18c, tnsnames

I have installed Oracle 18c xe in windows 10 , I am connecting Oracle but getting errors
TNS-01150: The address of the specified listener name is incorrect
TNS-01153: Failed to Process the String: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost))(PORT=1521))

Listener failed to start.

This is my TNSNAMES.ORA:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\dkcal\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost))(PORT = 1521))

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

XEPDB1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1000))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XEPDB1)
    )
  )

LISTENER_XEPDB1 =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost))(PORT = 1000))
```

And my LISTENER.ORA:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\dkcal\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost))(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )

LISTENER_1 =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost))(PORT = 1000))
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\dkcal\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\dkcal\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr18.dll")
    )
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER_1 =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\dkcal\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\dkcal\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr18.dll")
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an out of order close parenthesis, here:

```
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost) -> ) <- (PORT=1521))
```

try this:

```
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
```